# Get fingerprints from a server

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

How do I get SSH fingerprints from a server, if I only have the IP address of the server and the server isn't listed in my `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file?

I would like to see some host keys. Here's what I tried in Ruby:

```ruby
net_ssh_session =
  Net::SSH::Transport::Session.new(
    target, :port => port, :timeout => timeout, :paranoid => Net::SSH::Verifiers::Null.new)
host_keys = net_ssh_session.host_keys
```

I couldn't get any host keys, if the server wasn't listed in my `~/.ssh/known_hosts`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting important parts of my article [Where do I get SSH host key fingerprint to authorize the server?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_hostkey)

> You should get an SSH host key fingerprint along with your credentials from a server administrator. Knowing the host key fingerprint and thus being able to verify it is an integral part of securing an SSH connection. It prevents [man-in-the-middle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).
>
> In the real world, most administrators do not provide the host key fingerprint.
>
> Instead you can ask anyone else who has a physical access to the server or who already knows the host key. The host key is only one and hence the same for all users. Also note that the host key fingerprint is generated from a public key part of the host key only. So it is not secret and can be safely sent over an unencrypted (yet trusted) communication channels.
>
> If you do not have anyone else to obtain the fingerprint from, you may need to connect to the server without knowing the fingerprint. Before connecting for the first time, ensure a security of your local machine and a line to the server. For example if you plan to connect to the server from an external site (e.g. from home or a client), but you have a physical access to the server site, connect from the server site the first time (e.g. your workplace).

Answer (score 1):

There is `ssh-keyscan`, but note that there is no guarantee that the keys you will get from this tool will be really the host keys of the server (there could be Man In The Middle attack going on and you might be connecting to completely different server).

You should get the host keys directly from the server using secure channel, from administrator, or using remote/local console.